# How to calculate tokens while reading a webpage

Tags: openai-api

I am planning to run this code.
But I will like to know how many tokens the bot will consume. (saving cost!)

```
import os
from embedchain import App

# Create a bot instance
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "YOUR API KEY"
elon_bot = App()

# Embed online resources
elon_bot.add("web_page", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elon_Musk")
elon_bot.add("web_page", "https://tesla.com/elon-musk")
elon_bot.add("youtube_video", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxZpaJK74Y4")

# Query the bot
elon_bot.query("How many companies does Elon Musk run?")
# Answer: Elon Musk runs four companies: Tesla, SpaceX, Neuralink, and The Boring Company
```

From:

https://github.com/embedchain/embedchain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One token generally corresponds to ~4 characters of text for common English text. This translates to roughly ¾ of a word (so 100 tokens ~= 75 words).
Ref:
https://platform.openai.com/tokenizer

You can use tiktoken to calculate the number of tokens for particular model.

https://github.com/openai/tiktoken

```
from tiktoken import Tokenizer 
from tiktoken.models import GPT2 

text = "blah blah .. more text here."

tokenizer = Tokenizer(GPT2) 
token_count = tokenizer.count_tokens(text) 
print(f"Token count: {token_count}")
```

For embedchain, you need to figure out how to extract the text from web pages that you added, and pass it to tiktoken to count.